# How to identify users that are still connecting to Parse.com API endpoint?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

The majority of users of an iOS app are connecting to the API endpoint of a self-hosted Parse Server. However some users are still using an old version of the app and connect to the Parse.com API endpoint.

The app version does not give any hint about the endpoint because the shift to the new endpoint happened gradually over multiple app versions.

How can those users be identified?

Comment: What do you mean with "identified"? Do you want to send them a push notification? You give far too little information about your current setup for us to be able to suggest a solution. My favorite solution would be: turn the old API end point off - all users that complain have obviously used this API endpoint.

Comment: Every connecting user has to have a corresponding user in `_User` class obviously. I want to identify the users by this user table. Simply turning off the API endpoint is exactly what I don't want to do, that's why I posted the question ;-)

Comment: do the users in the new end point have any properties in common with the Users in the old one? If they have nothing in common -> nothing you can do; if they have something in common -> filter the ones out of the old end point that have a corresponding user in the new one and the rest are the ones that have yet to upgrade / update.

Comment: Both user groups are indistinguishable by their data. Otherwise I would just filter them in the database, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Implement a cloud code function `afterSave` for the `_Installation` class on Parse.com to set a flag for the connected user. The `_Installation` class is updated every time the app is launched. Because the cloud code is only executed on the Parse.com API endpoint, only those users connection to that endpoint will be flagged. Although it takes a couple of days/weeks to flag those users.

Depending on the app logic, a quicker way to flag them is to send a silent push notification if that triggers a write operation to the database and setup cloud code to flag depending on that.